# Specific Page (view/read) restriction of mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki

I am working with mediawiki in my project. I want to restrict specific pages from users and it should be only accessed(along with edit, move and upload rights) to some group of users and administrator.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of different access control extensions with different mechanism and effectiveness, you can check full list here: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:Page_specific_user_rights_extensions

You may try [PageSecurity](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:PageSecurity) (requires patches to core files) or [SimpleSecurity](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SimpleSecurity).

Comment: I have already viewed these pages. still cant help to get to the solution.

Comment: Did you try one of these extensions ? What issues you've encountered ?

Comment: Actually I have tried with simple security with my mediawiki 1.28 , but I am not able to integrate that.